# Unknown email password required after selecting iCloud backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

While restoring or setting up an iPhone (new or old) and choosing a backup from list of provided backup in my iCloud, I'm shown to enter a password for kmward@roadrunner.com , which I don't have idea of who's email that belongs to, I have lots of data on my iCloud and this scares me because why would Apple ask for some other account password? When I choose 'skip this step', I'm given a model message saying, "you must sign in to restore purchased content" and when I do tap skip, it restores from my own account (which earlier I provided credentials). 
Why does it ask for someone else's account password?

- Is my account hacked?
- Is my account linked to someone I don't know?
- Is my content being distributed to someone from kmward@roadrunner.com ?

What should I do to secure and remove this unknown account that Apple ask password for?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have two, one old, one new. although i have both issues on same, even when restoring.

Comment: This is new information, please add it to your op.

Comment: @Buscar웃  I edited the question, so i hope its fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this problem is very simple and isn't related to privacy issue or "left over ids" from refurbrished devices.

You have PIRATED music in your library.

When restoring the back-up, iOS tries to authenticate the PIRATED files and realizes the account has been locked down.

Comment: How do i get rid of it? When restored my devices, the music doesn't get back up to be downloaded. So where does the id comes? I don't remember copying any pirated music to my device as i don't use much of itunes with iPhone

Comment: Sort your media by "kind" and look for "Purchased..." then look at the info for the first file in the list and keep clicking "Next" until you see the kmward@roadrunner.com account. Delete it. Sync and enjoy.

Comment: Its hard to visualize what your saying, can you post a illustration?